# del function not working properly

Tags: python, del

Can you please help me with the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

stop = "0"

while(stop == "0"):
    infile = open(raw_input("Enter input filename: "), 'r')
    outfile = open(raw_input("Enter output filename: "), 'w')

    err = raw_input("Give max intensity: ")

    outfile.write("#" + "\n")

    for line in infile.readlines()[1:]:
        line = line.strip()
        line_col = line.split()
        if line_col[3] <= err:
            outfile.write(line + "\n")           
        else:
            del line
    stop = raw_input("Would like to quit the program? Yes = 1 No = 0: ")

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

The idea here is to read a file that has 5 columns of data. After prompting the user for a number (err) it is used to delete a line of data if the number in the 4th column of the file is above 'err'.

The problem is that for some reason not all the appropriate lines are deleted. If err = 500 then all 3 digit numbers above 500 (e.g 653.61511, 989.76770, 614.62500 etc...) will be deleted however those numbers that have 4 digits (e.g 1001.15637, 1628.09155, 2444.60400 etc...) are not!

The file that i am working with is given below:

-8.0   4.0    3.695   265.81021   265.8102
 -8.0   4.0    3.721   274.50510   274.5051
 -8.0   4.0    3.746   285.87451   285.8745
 -8.0   4.0    3.771   301.65869   301.6587
 -8.0   4.0    3.796   324.28391   324.2839
 -8.0   4.0    3.821   356.89609   356.8961
 -8.0   4.0    3.846   405.96741   405.9674
 -8.0   4.0    3.872   488.77600   488.7760
 -8.0   4.0    3.897   653.61511   653.6151
 -8.0   4.0    3.922   1001.15637   1001.1564
 -8.0   4.0    3.947   1628.09155   1628.0916
 -8.0   4.0    3.972   2444.60400   2444.6040
 -8.0   4.0    4.023   3092.76880   3092.7688
 -8.0   4.0    4.048   2488.82031   2488.8203
 -8.0   4.0    4.073   1653.13733   1653.1373
 -8.0   4.0    4.098   989.76770   989.7677
 -8.0   4.0    4.123   614.62500   614.6250

I am by no means an expert at coding in python so any help regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: What exactly do you expect the `del` function to do here? By my reading of this code it serves no purpose, and you'd get the exact same behavior removing the `else:` branch of the `if` statement entirely.

Comment: Using `del` on a variable is almost never what you want to do.

Comment: I want it to delete a line of data if the number in the 4th column is above 'err'

Comment: ...keep in mind that even if `del` removes 'line' from memory, 'line' was about to be replaced in memory anyhow as soon as another line is read, so the use of del doesn't change anything about how your code operates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with `del` -- which, by the way, doesn't do anything here -- it's with comparing two strings.

Open up a Python interpreter and write:

```
"1001" < "3"
```

You'll get back `True`. That's because Python is doing a lexicographical comparison of two *strings*. What you want is to compare two numbers, like this:

```
1001 < 3
```

Which gives back `False`, as we'd expect.

In your code, `line_col[3]` is a string, as is `err`, so Python does the first type of comparison. You'll need to convert both to numbers to get behavior you'd like, by writing, for instance: `float(line_col[3]) < float(err)`.

Comment: No problem. Make sure you read some of the other answers to understand exactly why `del` doesn't do anything here, and when you'd actually want to use it.